# Replace "1Don't do that" with "_1Don_t_do_that"

Tags: regex, xcode

I need to modify the keys of a key value file as follows:

```
"1Don't do that" = "some value"
```

to

```
"_1Don_t_do_that" = "some value"
```

- prepend with underscore if string starts with a number
- replace any non alphanumeric char with underscore
- do not alter the value string

I can do it in several steps if necessary

I've tried things like `\"\w+[^\w]\w+\" =`  but it doesn't account for multiple spaces and does not single or double quotes.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: +1 for explaining aim sufficiently, and showing what you've tried.

Comment: What language/flavor are you using ?

Comment: Your to-example is has no `"` between `=` and `some` - is that an oversight or part of your requirement?

Comment: @Hamza: if possible I would like to do it manually in xcode, if not in Java

Comment: @Philipp : I generally need to match any nor alphanumeric char. But in my examples the quotes are not.

Comment: XCode covers a bunch of languages; can you be more specific about what you mean?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler if it is simple enough I will do a find/replace. Otherwise I will write a small Java program

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think he means Xcode's Find and Replace dialog in the GUI. So the regex is for whatever flavor Xcode uses internally.

Comment: OK: you can tell I don't use IDEs in general and XCode in particular.

Comment: **edit war started !**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that none of your quotes are escaped, this should work:

```
(?:(?<=")(?=\d)|[^\w"])(?=[^"]*"\s*=)
```

This matches

- either the position between `"` and a digit
- or a non-alphanumeric character (except a quote),

but only if they are followed by a single quote and an equals sign.

[See it live on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bE3uU4).

Comment: Thanks. I finally wrote a little program in Java to handle this task and it works amazingly well.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what regex flavor Xcode uses, but as long as it supports positive lookahead `(?=)`, this series of replacements should work:

1. Prepend with underscore if string starts with a number

   - find: `^"(?=\d)`
   - replace all: `"_`
2. Replace any non alphanumeric char with underscore, making sure that the value string is after, not part of, what we're changing.

   - find: `[^a-zA-Z0-9](?=[^"]*"\s*=\s*"[^"]*")`
   - replace all: `_`

The second step assumes that quote characters never occur in the value string; tell me if you need to handle backslash-escaped quote characters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate the time you took. Unfortunately it did not work exactly as expected on Xcode as the opening quote were matched.